# Can't re-use Https Test Scripts recorder to complete actions because response code- 401 showing

Tags: testing, jmeter, jwt, token, http-status-code-401

Check the below scenario:

1. Earlier I recorded a **Https Test-script** recorder and completed "**Login", "File-upload" & "Log-out"** operations.
2. today I again tried to **run** or **re-use** the **recorded samplers**, now it's giving me the 401, unauthorized or Expired JWt token errors.
3. I want to get rid of this error and re-use the recorded samplers to complete my actions in teh system.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPIlp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your request is failing to to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), when you recorded your test it contained a [JWT Token](https://jwt.io/) which probably was active for some time and has expired since then.

You need to add a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (most probably [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)) as a child of the `login` request, extract the token and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and substitute recorded hard-coded value with the variable from the JSON Extractor.